# wp_posts query various Custom post types into report wordpress

Tags: sql, wordpress

I have `CPT cars` and `CPT Event` class which the cars are racing in.

I need to be able to do up a report for an event (race)  I need to be able to display the personal details of the person, Car details and event class entered into.  This information is all stored in the `wp_posts` table and the `wp_postmeta` table.  They are all linked by the `post_id` and en example of the `meta_values` is `wpcf-car-type`, `wpcf-cc`, `wpcf-aspiration-type`  etc..
How can I query all this information into one report ?

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
 $args = array(
                    'post_type'     =>  array('cars','Events'),
                    'post_status'   => 'publish',
                    'posts_per_page' => -1,      
              );
$html = '';
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :
   while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
        $html .= 'Title : ' . get_the_title();
        $html .= 'Description : ' . get_the_content();
        $html .= 'Car Type : '.get_post_meta(get_the_ID(),'wpcf-car-type',true);
        $html .= 'CC : '.get_post_meta(get_the_ID(),'wpcf-cc',true);
        $html .= 'Aspiration Type : '.get_post_meta(get_the_ID(),'wpcf-aspiration-type',true);
   endwhile;
endif; 
return $html;
```

Comment: can you share your code? have you added proper post_type slug in array and there is available posts for this type as publish status ?

Comment: function get_orders()
{
$args = array(
                    'post_type'     =>  array('cars','qsot-event'),
                    'post_status'   => 'publish',
                    'posts_per_page' => -1,      
              );

$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :
   while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
        echo 'Title : ' . get_the_title();

Comment: echo 'Car Type : '.get_post_meta(get_the_ID(),'wpcf-car-type',true);
        echo 'CC : '.get_post_meta(get_the_ID(),'wpcf-cc',true);
        echo 'Aspiration Type : '.get_post_meta(get_the_ID(),'wpcf-aspiration-type',true);
   endwhile;
endif; 
}   
add_shortcode('get_orders', 'get_orders');

Comment: okay you are using this as shortcode then you have to add this in one variable and then return it. check my edited answer for this

Comment: that is bringing back some but not the car details like car cc from the post_meta table

Comment: you have to check in database table "wp_postmeta" for which meta key you are inserting data.